# Laravel Carbon - Reloading Current Time

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, php-carbon

I could not find any document in relation to what I am trying to solve, hence I am asking it here.

My controller pulls a Carbon Date using this:

`$utctime = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();`

That code allows me to display the UTC time on my page. The problem comes in the fact that Carbon only loads the time once (on page load) and it stays at that time. What I want is to Carbon to display the real-time and not require the page to reload.

I am guessing it might not be possible the update the time, as Carbon is not front-end? If so, how would you go about making the time update every second instead of it not updating at all? - Maybe there is something for the front-end that I can use?

Comment: Like some kind of clock, right?

Comment: Why not just pulling it once on page load and then let JavaScript to keep updating it?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Giedrius I guess that would be the best way to do it! (Unless there is a 'Carbon' way to do it.)

Comment: I was exactly to point that out...a clock routine with javascript....@spacetravel can you post the code where you render the `$utctime` in the View?

Comment: @spacetravel Well yes the "Carbon" way could be just making AJAX request every second to retrieve the date, but that seems wildly unnecessary. You can do the initial date without JS as well, but if you want the date to be in sync with your server date (independent on user's timezones perhaps and their clock), then yes would be best to send initial date from the back-end and then let JS take care of updating it in real-time.

Comment: @Hackerman I use a `{{$utctime}}` in my view. The clock is in my header, so I use a View Provider to add it to my header for each page: `$utctime = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();`, `View::share(compact('utctime'));`

Comment: @Giedrius - I will probably use the Javascript solution then. Seems the quickest and easiest way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a basic ticking clock in Javascript is fairly straightforward:

```
<div id="time"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showTime() {
    var date = new Date(),
        utc = new Date(Date.UTC(
          date.getFullYear(),
          date.getMonth(),
          date.getDate(),
          date.getHours(),
          date.getMinutes(),
          date.getSeconds()
        ));

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = utc.toLocaleTimeString();
  }

  setInterval(showTime, 1000);
</script>
```

This would be entirely front-end based, and ensure there isn't a "jump" between the initially rendered server-time and the user's local time.

Comment: Would it be possible to output UTC time instead my local time? The clock works, but it displays my local time. Thanks!

Comment: @spacetravel Edited. JS really isn't the nicest language for manipulating dates, so if you want to do anything more complicated than this, I'd recommend looking into a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js, you can also define the timezone or display UTC time

```
moment.utc().format();
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/
https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/